# Obtain common elements from 2 lists of unequal length

Tags: r

My data structure is as follows:

```
xy
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
[[2]]
[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

xyz
[[1]] 
[[1]] [[1]]
[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
[[2]]
[[2]] [[1]]
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
[[3]]
[[3]] [[1]]
[1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

I want to find the common elements present in each subset of the list.
My expected output is:

```
New_list
[[1]]
[1] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
[[2]]
[1] 5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 
[[3]]
[1] 6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Initially I tried the following command:

```
Map(intersect,xy,xyz)
```

However, its showing the following error:

> Warning message:
>   In mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) :
>     longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter**

I am guessing it has got something to do with the unequal lengths of the lists as my command works fine with lists of equal length.

Comment: can you please dput your data?

Comment: The intersection between the third element of `xy` and the third element of `xyz` should be empty, since the third element of `xy` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l1 <- list(1:10,2:12)

l2 <- list(list(3:10),list(5:15),list(6:12))


lapply(unlist(l2,recursive=F),function(x){intersect(unlist(l1),x)})
```

Comment: Actually, this is same as akrun's answer. Don't see any difference.

Comment: The first part is different but you're right. Pretty darn close.

Answer (score 4):

We `unlist` the first `list`, flatten the second and loop over the `list` and use `intersect`

```
lapply(do.call(c, xyz), function(x) intersect(x, unlist(xy)))
#[[1]]
#[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

#[[2]]
#[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

#[[3]]
#[1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

#### data

```
xy <- list(1:10, 2:12)
xyz <- list(list(3:10), list(5:15), list(6:12))
```

Comment: or `lapply(xyz,function(x) intersect(x[[1]], unlist(xy)))`